# How to get element values from an XML column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sql-server-2005

I have the XML below in a column.  I need to get to \Report\Criterias\Criteria (where name="Advertisers")\Elements\Element(where name="ListViewAvailable").  From here I need to list all the numbers that are in the Value element.

So far I got:

```
SELECT xmlColumn.query('/Report/Criterias/Criteria/Elements/Element')
from tbl
```

but no idea how to filter.

```
<Report>
  <Criterias>
    <Criteria name="Date Range">
        ...
    </Criteria>

    <Criteria name="Advertisers">
      <Elements>
        <Element name="CheckBoxOne">
          <Value>0</Value>
        </Element>
        <Element name="ListViewAvailable">
          <Value>314</Value>
          <Value>57</Value>
          <Value>18886</Value>
          <Value>7437</Value>
        </Element>
      </Elements>
    </Criteria>
    <Criteria name="Revenue Types">
      ...
    </Criteria>
  </Criterias>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter using predicate (`[]`) in combination with `CROSS APPLY` to shred the XML on `Value` elements level :

```
SELECT C.value('.', 'int') AS Value
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY t.xmlColumn.nodes('
    /Report/Criterias/Criteria[@name="Advertisers"]
    /Elements/Element[@name="ListViewAvailable"]
    /Value
') T(C)
```